# Bootstrap: Aligning two buttons on the same row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically what I'm attempting to do it to get two buttons on the opposite side of the website but on the same row. Here's what it looks like: 
[image]

And here's the code for what I have:

```
             <div class="panel-footer"><!-- panel-footer -->

              <div class="previous">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                  </button>
              </div>

              <div class="next">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                  </button>
              </div>

          </div><!-- end panel-footer -->
```

And here's the CSS for the classes 'previous' and 'next'.

```
.previous {
text-align: left;
}

.next {
text-align: right;
}
```

Thanks. I'm using bootstrap if that helps.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Wrap them in two separate columns like this:

```
<div class="panel-footer row"><!-- panel-footer -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
        <div class="previous">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">   
        <div class="next">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end panel-footer -->
```

By the way, you can use the built in helper classes text-left / text-right like I've done on the column divs so you don't need to add the extra css.  In that case you can remove the extra divs you've added.

Comment: you beat me to it, and i also forgot the text-right class on my answer

Comment: BTW, classes `previous` and `next` can be merged with upper divs: `<div class="col-xs-6 text-left previous">...</div>` and `<div class="col-xs-6 text-right next">...</div>`.

Answer (score 6):

I thought Bootstrap automatically does this floating for you if you wrap it in the div .row since it's based on a grid?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="pull-left">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
     </button>
 </div>

 <div class="pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </button>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Bootstrap 4 Answer**

The above answers are all Boostrap 3 specific, so I'm updating the accepted answer.

**Glyphicons don't exist in Bootstrap 4**, so you'll have to use something like [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/)

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- panel-footer -->
    <div class="col-6 text-left">
        <div class="previous">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <!--No glyphicons in Bootstrap 4. Insert icon of choice here-->
                <span class=""></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <div class="next">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class=""></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try what HaukurHaf said, it will work. Simple floating method.

Or you can also put those two .previous and .next divs in .col- classes and then wrap them in a row div. So it would read:

```
<div class="panel-footer">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 previous">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 next">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way your are following Bootstrap's column layout.

Comment: How did I not think of columns... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use flexbox:

```
<div class="flexbuttons">
<button></button>
<button></button>
</div>
    
<style>
.flexbuttons{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, nice updated answer! I started with this then added in bootstrap classes and font-awesome icons: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72664382/5070253

Answer (score 0):

You need to float the divs containing the buttons to the left and right.  Since you are using Bootstrap, I recommend that you use the built in .pull-right and .pull-left classes.

Give the previous div the .pull-left class and the next div the pull-right class.

You might have to make the next button come first in your html source.

You could also just add float:left; to your existing .previous class and float:right; to the .next class.

Better yet, just get rid of those previous/next divs and apply the pull-left/pull-right classes directly to the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I would use *float* in your css

```
.previous {
float: left;
}

.next {
float: right;
}
```

You can test this option here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Nd5j/).

Answer (score 0):

**2020+ Updated answer:**

- Bootstrap classes [flex-box and justify-content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content)
- Font-awesome icons instead of glyphicons (Not in Bootstrap 4)

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </button>
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `justify-content-between`

```
    <div class="panel-footer row justify-content-between">
        <div class="previous">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="next">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```