# 2 submit button for 2 forms - The submit button which align horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have 2 forms that pass all hidden input data to another page. both have submit button which have post method.i am using bootstrap css framework and material bootstrap css design overlap with it. My problem is that 2 submit button aligns  vertically like below

submit

submit

i want the 2 submit buttons aligns horizontally like below,

submit  submit

what css code i have to apply for these change?

```
<form action="generate_p.php" method="post" >
             <input type="hidden" name="sdat" value="<?php echo $start; ?>"/>
             <input type="hidden" name="edat" value="<?php echo  $end; ?>"/>
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="EXPORT"  class="btn btn-raised btn-success"/>
            </form>

<form action="generate_pi.php" method="post" >
             <input type="hidden" name="sdat" value="<?php echo $start; ?>"/>
             <input type="hidden" name="edat" value="<?php echo  $end; ?>"/>
             <input type="submit" name="submi" value="EXPO"  class="btn btn-raised btn-success"/>
            </form>
```

Comment: Where's your code ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499767/bootstrap-aligning-two-buttons-on-the-same-row Hopefully this solves the problem.

Comment: Mine is input submit , the link explained about buttons. @Krandalf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Bootstrap for that.
Just simply use `style="display:inline-block;"` to change your design.

```html
<form action="generate_p.php" method="post" style="display:inline-block;">
             <input type="hidden" name="sdat" value="<?php echo $start; ?>"/>
             <input type="hidden" name="edat" value="<?php echo  $end; ?>"/>
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="EXPORT"  class="btn btn-raised btn-success"/>
            </form>

<form action="generate_pi.php" method="post" style="display:inline-block;">
             <input type="hidden" name="sdat" value="<?php echo $start; ?>"/>
             <input type="hidden" name="edat" value="<?php echo  $end; ?>"/>
             <input type="submit" name="submi" value="EXPO"  class="btn btn-raised btn-success"/>
            </form>
```

Comment: Very Thanks. 

@Md. Nasir Uddin Bhuiyan  Itz Works.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I answer here @Jees K Denny.
You can give each input a

```
<div class="col-lg-6"></div>
```

Works the same as with buttons.