# Bootstrap buttons in one line

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button

[Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fAqP.png)

Here is my code, and i dont know how to place the buttons side to side. (btw I'm new at coding)

```
<div class="second">
           <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
               <form>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" formaction="1klasse.html">1.klasse </button>
               </form>
           </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
                <form>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" formaction="1klasse.html">2.klasse </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap, there are a few things you need to know:

.col class will not work without putting the class within .container and .row classes. The other important thing is that the column numeric sizes add up to 12; right now yours add to 20. So your code should look more like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
       <form>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" formaction="1klasse.html">1.klasse </button>
       </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      <form>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" formaction="1klasse.html">1.klasse </button>
       </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a codepen to show it working](https://codepen.io/adphughe/pen/jmjLvQ)

[Refer to Bootstrap documentation on grids as well](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 4):

Just put the buttons inside the same form and div

```
<div class="second">
     <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
           <form>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" formaction="1klasse.html">1.klasse </button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" formaction="1klasse.html">2.klasse </button>
            </form>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row second">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <form>
                 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" formaction="1klasse.html">1.klasse </button>
            </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
            <form>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" formaction="1klasse.html">2.klasse </button>
            </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="second">
       <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
           <form>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" formaction="1klasse.html">1.klasse </button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" formaction="1klasse.html">2.klasse </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The buttons were in different columns, so it went one line down.

> Read more about [Bootstrap grid system](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Before looking into the answer below, I suggest that you read about boostrap grid system. Each row has 12 columns.

Your first `<div>` used up 12 columns, and that's why the second button of the second `<div>` is on the new row/line.

More details can be found here: 
[Bootstrap: Aligning two buttons on the same row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499767/bootstrap-aligning-two-buttons-on-the-same-row)